# Should users of a class call new directly?

Tags: vb.net

Or should they do something like this instead

```
   Public Shared Function createOrders(ammount As String, base As String, quote As String, exchange As ExchangesClass, time As String, price As String, id As String, sellinginsteadofbuying As String) As OrdersAtExchange
        Dim a = New OrdersAtExchange
        a._ammount = Val(ammount)
        a._exchangeObject = exchange
        a._base = base
        a._quote = quote
        a._time = Date.Parse(time)
        a._price = Val(price)
        a._id = id
        a._market = CoinClass.MarketBaseQuoted(exchange.Exchange, base, quote)

        If a._market Is Nothing Then
            Dim b = 1
        End If
        a._isSellingInsteadOfBuying = sellinginsteadofbuying.ToLower.Trim = "sell"
        Return a
    End Function
```

Basically I saw programs where instead of using new they simply uses a createObject function. It's shared.

I sort of see that it's a good idea. I wonder where.

Using new in vb.net is a bit complex because one new function may need to call another new function. Also some variables are "initialized". And some are set within the function.

Using that shared create objects seem to eliminate the issue.

But is it really a good idea?

I think I remember objective-c also do this sort of thing.

Comment: What you're seeing above is possibly a little bit like a Factory Method (although a fairly pointless one). Or maybe it exists bcause the class implements the Singleton Pattern, although we can't tell just from that code. Anyway what you decide to do depends entirely on your circumstances and requirements. There is no "best" way. And none of this seems particularly specific to VB or even .NET, just general object-oriented principles. There are established design patterns and methodologies you can choose to follow if you wish, what you choose depends on what suits your situation.

Comment: I view code like that as less of a factory method and something closer to an [inner platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).  It is really just a "helper" method which simplifies almost nothing since each property has to be passed to this method. Nothing is gained or simplified by passing 7-8 parameters to something versus setting them directly.   Passing dates and numerics as strings which then must be converted is also dubious.  It also looks as though `Option Strict` may not be on which would be more beneficial

Comment: option strict is on.

Answer (score 1):

Using shared functions or creating a new object by users of class totally depends on objective of the class.

Using shared functions for creating instance is somewhat similar to implementing a constructor for a class to set it state.

Some of scenarios when to use shared class would be.
1. when you do not want to give control to outside world for object creation of your class.
2. When you always want object of class to have particular state when created.
3. Shared functions can also be used in case of Singleton design pattern implementation.

Similarly if you want users to have complete control over object creation of your class and assign its state, you can allow using new keyword for object creation.

Its always a good idea to have a class which is always at the safe state and any given point of time which can be achieved by shared function.

Hope this helps !!!